# Altering the URL on all ajax-calls from ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using Ext.Ajax.request() in lots of places in my ExtJS Application.

Is there a way to have a function run just before the Ajax-call is made, that can alter the URL just before it is sent?

I would like to add an extra query-string to all of my Ajax requests dynamically.

I do not want to go and edit all my Ajax-calls manually.

Comment: There should be a central AJAX handler in EXT that you could extend or patch into (you get the source code). I'm not sure where, but that's a start.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Was hopeing for some code though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what we do:

```
Ext.data.Connection.override({
    //add an extra parameter to the request to denote that ext ajax is sending it
    request: function(options){
        var me = this;
        if(!options.params)
            options.params = {};
        options.params.ext_request = true;

        return me.callOverridden(arguments);
    }
});
```

Connection is the class that Ext.Ajax inherits from.

Comment: Cleaner solution. Good job :)

Comment: Just nothing that, if anyone else works in this code base, they should be aware of the override so they don't wonder where the extra parameter comes from ;)

Answer (score 4):

`Ext.Ajax` has a `beforequest` event that fires before any `request` happens:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function(conn, options, eOpts) {
    console.log('The options parameter contains the options');
    console.log(' going to the request method');
});
```